# Dovecot not attempting authentication

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, dovecot

I am in the early stages of migrating an OS X mail installation (UW imapd/Exim/mbox) to a Ubuntu cloud VM using Dovecot/Exim/Maildir. I am starting simply: Exim is running fine, receiving mail and appending correctly to Maildir mailboxes in /home/xx/Mail.

I am trying to configure Dovecot to read the mail there. Clients are connecting OK via SSL/port 993 but not getting any further. Syslog shows repeated:

```
localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=217.16.xxx.xxx, lip=109.74.xxx.xxx, TLS handshaking: Disconnected
```

`/etc/pam.d/dovecot` has:

```
auth    required        pam_unix.so nullok
account required        pam_unix.so
```

and my dovecot.conf is:

```
# 2.0.19: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.15.4-x86_64-linode45 x86_64 Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS 
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = maildir:~/Mail
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

I suspect I am missing something in the config. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `args = dovecot` in the `passdb` block.

Comment: `doveadm -D auth test` and set `mail_debug=yes` and `auth_debug=yes` in `conf.d/10-logging.conf` to get more info about what's going wrong.